# is it possible to Nifi application backup and restore?

Tags: apache-nifi

Is there a way to backup & restore apache Nifi application data like nifi-flow-audit.h2.db & controller services configuration data?

Answer (score 5):

The controller services configuration is serialized into `$NIFI_HOME/conf/flow.xml.gz`. You can copy this file to any NiFi instance with the same `nifi.sensitive.props.key` value in `$NIFI_HOME/conf/nifi.properties` and it will be used to define the entire flow (CS, processors, reporting tasks, etc.).

The `nifi-flow-audit.h2.db` is a local database containing the audit records of the flow changes. You can copy that file to remote disk and restore it from there as well.

In general, you want to back up everything in the `$NIFI_HOME/conf` directory to restore the application configuration, and the three repositories (`content_repository`, `flowfile_repository`, and `provenance_repository`) if you want the exact state of the application. More information on the [repositories](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/nifi-in-depth.html) and [setting up NiFi for easier upgrades](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/1.x.0+to+1.x.0+Upgrade) here.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the backup options in Nifi Toolkit's File Manager.

Sample command

```
# backup NiFi installation
# option -t may be provided to ensure backup of external boostrap.conf file
./file-manager.sh
-o backup
–b /tmp/nifi_bak
–c /usr/nifi_old
-v
```

Source: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/toolkit-guide.html#file-manager